# Can not load mod_fcgid in Apache/2.2.21 (Win32)

Tags: apache, mod-fcgid

I am using Apache/2.2.21 (Win32)

I downloaded mod_fcgid from  http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win32/modules-2.2/mod_fcgid-2.3.7-win32.zip

I used

```
LoadModule mod_fcgid modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

to load mod_fcgid

But I am getting this error

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 86 of F:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `mod_fcgid' in file F:/xampp/apache/modules/mod_fcgid.so: No error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```